# where can i find online c++ design patterns and exercises?

Tags: c++

i need to start refine my memory so i like to practice a bit 
do you know good site like : http://www.blackbeltfactory.com for java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some that looked promising on a quick perusal (and I'm adding to my own reading queue):

- [Wikibooks entry on Design Patterns in C++](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns)
- [Similar question answered responses on CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=327982)
- [C++ FAQ section on some design patterns](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/subject-index.html)
- [C++ headers from Head First Design Patterns to inspect](http://hfdp-cpp.sourceforge.net/)

Have fun!  (Sorry - don't know of any with a quiz for free - although the HFDP book likely has chapter-based ones)

Answer (score 2):

Those links are a "must have" in your bookmarks:

- [Cplusplus Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/)
- [C++ Reference](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/start)
- [Cprogramming](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/)
- [Cplus About](http://cplus.about.com/)
- [IBM XL C/C++ V7.0](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrapxgpp.htm)
- [More C++ Idioms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category%3aMore_C++_Idioms).

Another thousand usefull links can be found by googling. One of them will fit your taste.

Comment: Thanks but i really need the exercises more

Comment: The more c++ idioms link looks useful

Answer (score -1):

You already got quite a few references so far, I just want to add this one, *Data & Object Factory* at http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx.

Comment: The link is not working

Comment: I posted that link 9 years ago. They probably removed that in the meanwhile. All they have now is this: https://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns

Answer (score -2):

I would say you can use java exercises....just write it in c++, its the same...
Grab [http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1299852356&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)
from The "Gang of Four":
Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides

For reference and you'll be set up :)